# ASP MVC 3 Telerikgrid sending Rowvesion(byte[]) to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

I have a telerik MVC 3 grid, that contains checkbox column. if the user select multiple items and clicks a button, i need to send the id and byte[] timestamp(for concurrency) to the controller. user can select any number of items, so i dont want to bring the full row information to the controller. Also, it's a postback on the click. Is there a way to post the list of Id and timestamp together to the controller on the button click. Thanks in advance. View code of the grid columns from my app

```
.Columns(columns =>
               {
                   columns.LoadSettings(Model.GridColumnSettings);
                   columns.Template(
                                       @<text>
                                            <input name="SelectedRecords" type="checkbox" value="@(item.Id))" title="Select"
                                                @if ((Model.SelectedRecords!= null) && (Model.SelectedRecords.Contains(item.Id)))
                                                {

                                                            <text>checked="checked"</text> 
                                                }
                                            />                                                
                                       </text>                                                                               
                                   ).Title("Select").Width(23).HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:center" });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer for this is using Convert.FromBase64String and Convert.ToBase64String for sending and recieving byte[]. i found this from 
http://junmeng.blogspot.com/2006/05/optimistic-concurrency-control-using.html

thanks for the your time Eddie

Answer (score 1):

Would this be with DataBinding?  I only messed with Telerik briefly, but did have a grid running. I used ajax to call my control as such:

```
.DataBinding(dataBinding => dataBinding.Ajax()
            .Select("_Paging", "Home")
            .Update("_Paging", "Home")
            .Insert("Create", "Home"))
```

I'd suspect you could pass variables to the controller as you would in an action link (though I've not tried this...)

```
.Select("_Paging", "Home", new { timestamp = DateTime.Now }, null)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Timestamp is not time. its a rowversion (byte[])in database for checking concurrency in data,which i need to carry it back to the server, also i need to send the id and the timestamp(rowversion) to the server. one more complication is grid values are multi select.so, i need to send list of <int id, byte[] timestamp> to the server

Comment: Helped me in someway, Thanks for the answer Eddie, will wait for sometime and mark it as answer